# Serial input string equals other string not working

Tags: c#

I have faced an issue when writing an if statement that compares 2 strings

```
String str1 = Serial.ReadLine(); //The serial reads "R_011"
str1.Trim();

if(str1 == "R_011"){
  //Action
}
```

This doesn't work, as it interprets that both strings are different.

I've realised that if I replace the Serial input with the string I'm comparing it with

```
str1 = "R_011";
```

it works perfectly, so it has to be something related with what Serial reads.

Anyone that can help me? Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that `Serial.ReadLine` is bringing some hidden character that you can't see but it's there

Comment: Try to *decode* the string from the `Serial`: `Console.Write(str1 => string.Join(" ", str1.Select(c => ((int) c).ToString("x4"))))` and see what is the *actual* string (with all its hidden characters) you have

Comment: @Pikoh and how can I see what it is exactly bringing? I'm using visual studio

Comment: Read @DmitryBychenko comment

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You were right, all what the serial reads includes an extra at the end 000d, what should I do so?

Comment: `(char) 0x000d == '\r'` `Trim()` - see Felipe Oriani's answer - will do

Comment: @SergiodePropios, ```0x0D``` is a carriage return. Use ```str = str.TrimEnd('\r');```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `Trim()` it returns a new string. Set the result on your reference `str1`. Try also using `Equals` method and `StringComparison` parameter to ignore case. Try this:

```
string str1 = Serial.ReadLine(); 
str1 = str1.Trim();

if (str1.Equals("R_011", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  //Action
}
```

Comment: You could also just do: `String str1 = Serial.ReadLine().Trim();`

Comment: Yes, it could, just to illustrate to OP.

Comment: probably `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is a slightly better choice

Comment: +1 for `Equals(...)`; in this particular case we can be sure that `str1` is not `null`; in *general* case, however `string.Equals(str1, str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: This was the correct solution, by declaring str1.Trim(); only it didn't do anything, but adding str1 = str1.Trim(); worked perfectly, although no str1.Equals() was needed. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try to use string instead of String, also try this:

```
if(Convert.ToString(str1) == "R_011"){
```

//Action
}

Comment: What are the differences between `String` and `string`?

Comment: ```string``` and ```System.String``` are exact same things.

Comment: Tell me, what is the solution then?

Comment: @Taco2, solution is something else but not your answer. Converting ```System.String``` to ```string``` have no sense as they are same type.

Comment: @Taco2 this didn't change anything, the solution was removing extra characters on the input.